# Modify copied array without modifying the original array js

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let payBackAmount = cash - price;
  let tempArr = cid.slice();

  for (let i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++) {
    tempArr[i][1] = 0;
  }
  console.log("cid is", cid);
}
checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],

  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
]);
```

Here I am trying to copy an array from the parameterized function. `cid` is the array which I am trying to pass inside the function and I am trying to copy it into `tempArr`. Later when modifying the values of `tempArr` , the values of `cid` is changing as well.
I have also tried copying the values using `let tempArr=[...cid]` and `let tempArr=cid.slice(0)`

Comment: You made a shalow copy, not a deep one. `cid` (great naming by the way :D) is a 2d array. If you add or remove elements from `tempArr`, the changes won't occur on `cid`, however, **the elements** of the array are still references, since they are arrays too. A quick and dirty way to do that is `const tempArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cid));`

Comment: @Cid Thanks a lot for your explanation and the link. I really thought copying would be same since I was just trying to copy the contents of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in the above code when you are copying one array to an other array the slice method and spread operator from javascript does a shallow copy, for your usecase you might want to do a deep clone of the object you can do `let tempArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cid))` , instead of this you can also use `deepClone` from Lodash to deep clone a object

also please look at this thread [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) to know more about shallow clone and deep clone